How to Move an Element to the Right Side in Kendo TabStrip in Angular14 using Kendo Ui
I'm working with the Kendo UI TabStrip and want to move one of the tabs to the right side, as shown in the picture below. I tried using margin-left, but it's not working as expected due to conflicts between class names.

I tried by selecting class name and existing kendo UI documents but it doesn't have any example or even demo code in angular 14

Did you try using margin-left: auto with a selector for ... .k-tabstrip-items-wrapper .k-item:last-child {}? It seems to work. If it doesn't work for you, can you set up a stackblitz demo? (I checked on the latest Kendo version so the class names might be a bit different in your version but should still work the same)

@Shai,
I was able to get it done with the help of the following Kendo class. One issue I would like to mention is that if we  have use tab strip elsewhere, it might affect those classes as well. To avoid that issue, I created a div with a custom class selector, and using that, I was able to get it done.
Thanks for the help.
.custom-class .k-tabstrip-items .k-item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}


You don't have to add a div, you can put the class on the kendo-tabstrip element and target that

I found this stackblitz link with a demo updating it here for the future reference.
(DEMO LINK)[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjsn2d-iajko9]
